# What is the most efficient way to conduct a search into a OneToMany relationship using doctrine on Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository, symfony4

I have two entities (User and Product) with a OneToMany relationship. I want to retrieve all Product entities related to a specific User filtering them by a field called "finished". I will post the relevant information of those entities:

User Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $products;


    ....
```

Product Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Productepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $finished;


    ....
```

I am using the following code to filter my products, but is there any other more efficient way to do it?

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$products = $user->getProducts();
$filtered = [];

foreach ($products as $product){
    if(!$product->getFinished()){
        $filtered[] = $product;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions would be to use a database query like the following :
 - in the controller, you can do

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\ProductController;

use App\Repository\ProductRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\IsGranted;

class ProductController extends AbstractController
{
   /**
     * @Route("/products", methods={"GET"}, name="app_get_products")
     * @IsGranted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED")
     */
    public function listProduct(ProductRepository $repository)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $products = $repository->findBy([
            'user' => $user,
            'finished' => false
        ]);

        return $this->render('Product/list.html.twig', [
            'products' => $products,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Notice the request that is made : this is an attempt at a solution.